# Home page stopped importing static blocks

Tags: static-block

I was happily creating some new pages in magento 1.9.1 and I happen to go back and look at the home page and noticed it had stopped displaying the static blocks.

reference name="aside"

```
block type="core/template" name="custom_sites" template="blaa/blaa/custom-block.phtml"

    block type="core/template" name="block-content" as="block-content" template="blaa/blaa/sites.phtml"

        action method="setBlockId" block_id sites /block_id /action 
    /block
/block

block type="cms/block" name="home_bottom_content"

        action method="setBlockId" block_id home_bottom_content /block_id
```

/action 
    /block 
/reference

Neither are displaying any more, I have disabled everything I had done since I last noticed it working, but to no avail.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any ideas?

Thanks.

p.s. It stripped my tags so you will have to use your imagination a little. ^^

Comment: p.p.s I have tried using other static blocks that do work on other pages and renaming the ones I have already and no dice, it is just the home page seems to not display static blocks any more, as far as I can tell it is only the home page I looked at at least 30 others and they are all fine as are the categories that call static blocks.

Answer (score 2):

I also tried using the home pages static blocks on other pages and they work fine. the issue seems to be the home page not displaying blocks. Very strange.